Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')
`Windows; MS Code; "Electron" 5.0.4, simple desktop text editing app
I get the following error after clicking the save button; the button is located on the "index.html" page in a <div> the button will call the function at the bottom - the text in the "textarea" should write to the console --- when clicked the dev-tools report:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')
at saveText (index.html:69:37)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:38:77)

from this code:
function saveText(){ 
    let text = textarea.value 

    console.log(text) ipcRenderer.send('save', text)

index.html code below
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    
      <head>
        <title>Photon</title>
    
        <!-- Stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/photon.css">
        
        <!-- Stylesheets  for window text area-->
    <style>
        textarea{
            width: 100%;
            Height: 100%;
            resize: none;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
    </style>
      </head>
    
      <body>
        <!-- Wrap your entire app inside .window -->
        <div class="window">
          <!-- .toolbar-header sits at the top of your app -->
          <header class="toolbar toolbar-header"></header>
          <div class="toolbar-actions">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="increaseFont()">
                    <span class="icon icon-plus" ></span>
                  </button>
                  <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="decreaseFont()">
                    <span class="icon icon-minus"></span>
                  </button>
               </div>

# \<button class="btn btn-default pull-right" **onclick="saveText()**"\>

                  <span class="icon icon-download icon-text"></span>
                  Save
                </button>
              </div>    
          </header>
    
          <!-- Your app's content goes inside .window-content -->
          <div class="window-content">
            <textarea></textarea>
    
        </div>
        </div>
    <script>
    const electron = ('electron')
    const {ipcRenderer} = electron
    
    let textarea = document.querySelector('textarea')
    let defaultFontSize = 20
    
            function increaseFont(){
                textarea.style.fontSize = `${++defaultFontSize}px`
    
            }
            function decreaseFont(){
                textarea.style.fontSize = `${--defaultFontSize}px`        
    
            }
                    function saveText(){
                            let text = textarea.value
                            console.log(text)
                            ipcRenderer.send('save', text)
    
                     }
    </script>
    
    
      </body>
    </html> 

Main.js code:
const electron = require('electron')

const{app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = electron

app.on('ready', ()=>{

    let win = new BrowserWindow({
            webPreferences:{
                    nodeIntegration: true

            }

    })
    win.loadFile('index.html')

})

ipcMain.on('save', (event, text)=>{`your text`

// save the text to  file
console.log(text)

})

When I click the save button -- what-ever is in the "textarea" should be logged to console.
I have tried const electron = require('electron') inside the <script>  -- get require error
I have tried all the usual MS Code errors (close program, etc.)

const electron = ('electron') is wrong. This just sets it to the string, it doesn't import anything. And since the string doesn't have an ipcRenderer property, const {ipcRenderer} = electron sets ipcRenderer to undefined.

Still learning -- const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron") worked and I added contextIsolation: false, to the main.js - just after nodeIntegration: true
